# How do I find the gear icon to change from GNOME to Unity in 17.10?

Tags: unity, gnome, login, 17.10, gdm

On the login screen, we are supposed to click a gear icon to change between graphical different session types (such as different desktop environments). But I cannot see this gear icon in Ubuntu 17.10.

I am trying to change my desktop UI from GNOME to Unity, by selecting Unity in the menu on the login screen. How do I make this menu come up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's hidden a little bit:

In my VM login, you can see the standard screen - after I choose a user, you can then see the 'gear' icon... as shown below

[image]

[image]

Comment: If possible, also mark the gear in your picture

Comment: In my case there is no gear icon, although Unity has been installed. How to proceed?

Comment: @KristjanAdojaan There are a couple of possibilities at play here - Does your system normally log you in without a password?  I cannot see the icon until I also see the password entry prompt.